# @variables in rails from Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set @user_ctypes, but, when I access to it from a model, I get a **Nil** value. Why?

This is a TV Guide and an user (current_user) will set which are channels that it want to hide.
For example:
If the logged user doesn't have a satellite, he will have ctypes=['sat']. So any channels that is aired on satellite will be hidden to user.
If user is not logged, current_user is nil.

I'd want to use "default_scope" because any query to DB should be take care of which channels the user wants to see.

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_user_ctypes


  private

  def set_user_ctypes
    unless current_user.nil? 
      @user_ctypes = current_user.ctypes 
    else
      @user_ctypes =  Array.new
    end
  end
```

**Model**

```
 class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :programs, :dependent => :delete_all

       validates :name, :site, :ctype, :country, :presence => true


      default_scope {where.not(ctype: @user_ctypes)}
```

**User** (by Devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: you can't access instance variables in a model...

Comment: Is there any relationship between channels and users?

Comment: Instead of using `unless`/`else`, I'd suggest changing the code so you can use `if`/`else`. It will improve the readability of the code.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh No, no relationship

Answer (score 5):

A controller (your `ApplicationController` in this case) and a model (`Channel` in this case) are different instances of different objects and therefore don't share instance variables, hence you can't use instance variables in a model.

In general, to pass in a variable into a scope you'd normally do something like this:

```
scope :name lambda{|user_ctypes| { where.not(ctype: user_ctypes) }
```

Here's the problem, this is a default scope, and so you can't really share an instance variable created in a controller with it, because otherwise it's a little like a global variable.

Consider having a look at this bit and see if there's a better way of doing it, I always find with Rails that if it's hard to do/not doable it's probably wrong. Maybe you could consider using a normal scope or moving your logic elsewhere.

Comment: Setting session[:user_ctypes] instead of @user_ctypes in ApplicationController should be better?  Because I tried but I get undefined local variable or method `session' in Model

 default_scope {where.not(ctype: session[:user_ctypes])}

Comment: It won't work either - model objects don't have access to the session, that's only available in controllers, helpers and views.

Comment: @user1028100 eugen is right, it's the same thing again. Maybe give us some context, where is the scope used etc and see if we could help with refactoring it.

Comment: great thanks. So `current_user.ctypes`, is there a Ctype model? I think a habtm relationship between users and channels makes the most sense, and if this `Ctype` model is there, it could be modified slightly to do it. I'm guessing it isn't, but maybe we're lucky :) Ignoring that it doesn't actually work, I can see that what you've done is 'easier' but there's two db calls here, and it's just not scalable, there's probably features down the line which would be hampered by this. So yep, is `Ctype` a model or just an array in the user model?

Answer (score -3):

this happens because you have put as `private` the method where has been declared the `@user_ctypes` variable